# how to connect to bnb in nodejs web3

Tags: node.js

const express = require('express');

const Web3 = require('web3');

const Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
const app = express();

const  myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([abi],keycontract);

console.log(myContract.methods.totalSupply().call());

Error: connection not open on send()

Comment: Error: connection not open on send()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours.